# MongoDB - Find where at least one array value is missing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find all the documents where at least one of the values in an array is missing. For example:

Array: `["spanish", "dutch", "french"]`

The following docs **should** be selected:

```
{
    translations: [{ language: "spanish" }]
}
//and
{
    translations: [{ language: "spanish" }, { language: "french" }]
}
//and
{
    translations: [{ language: "german" }]
}
```

But these should **not** be selected:

```
{
    translations: [{ language: "spanish" }, { language: "french" }, { language: "dutch" }]
}
//and
{
    translations: [{ language: "spanish" }, { language: "french" }, { language: "dutch" }, { language: "german" }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$setIntersection` to find the documents with `$size` of intersection is less than three

```
{$expr : 
    {$lt :[
        {$size :{$setIntersection : ["$translations.language", ["spanish", "dutch", "french"]]}},
        3
    ]}
}
```

collection

```
> db.t80.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c68552ac6f8be1a888e6cc7"), "translations" : [ { "language" : "spanish" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c68552ac6f8be1a888e6cc8"), "translations" : [ { "language" : "spanish" }, { "language" : "french" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c68552ac6f8be1a888e6cc9"), "translations" : [ { "language" : "german" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c68552ac6f8be1a888e6cca"), "translations" : [ { "language" : "spanish" }, { "language" : "french" }, { "language" : "dutch" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c68552ac6f8be1a888e6ccb"), "translations" : [ { "language" : "spanish" }, { "language" : "french" }, { "language" : "dutch" }, { "language" : "german" } ] }
>
```

result

```
> db.t80.find({$expr  : {$lt :[{$size :{$setIntersection : ["$translations.language", ["spanish", "dutch", "french"]]}},3]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c68552ac6f8be1a888e6cc7"), "translations" : [ { "language" : "spanish" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c68552ac6f8be1a888e6cc8"), "translations" : [ { "language" : "spanish" }, { "language" : "french" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c68552ac6f8be1a888e6cc9"), "translations" : [ { "language" : "german" } ] }
>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use the [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) and [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operators

- `$all` returns all items that contain a certain key having all the items in a target array
- `$not` reverses that. Since **at least one missing = does not contain all**

The query would look like this:

```
{ "translations.language": { $not: { $all: ["spanish", "dutch", "french"] } } }
```

And with `Mongoose` and `Node.js` it will look like this:

```
const target = ["spanish", "dutch", "french"];

Lang.find({ "translations.language": { $not: { $all: target } } })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I think you just need to add `$not` before `$all` and this will be a perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
db.docs.find({$or: [
 {translations: {$not: {$elemMatch: {language: "spanish"}}}},
 {translations: {$not: {$elemMatch: {language: "dutch"}}}},
 {translations: {$not: {$elemMatch: {language: "french"}}}},
]})
```